# How to change the shadow color in Blender Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, edit-mode, shadows

I want to change the color of the shadow casting by a *cube* to green. While it's very easy to do it in *Blender Internal* (you select the *lamp*, go to the *Lamp data* header and change the shadow's color in the *Shadow* panel) in *Cycles* there're no such options. How to achieve it in *Cycles*?
[image]

Answer (score 15):

With the *Cycles renderer* enabled select the *cube*, give it a *new material* and set the material nodes as pictured below. Use the ***Is Camera Ray*** of the *Light Path* node as a factor for mixing the *Diffuse* and *Transparent* nodes (***Is Shadow Ray*** works good as well).
[image]

Change the *Hue*, *Saturation* and *Value* values of the *Transparent* shader to change the shadow's *color*, *intensity* and *transparency*.
[image]

Here's the animated test using the changes mentioned above:
[image]

Comment: Shadow ray is the proper way to do this as camera ray will color reflections as well which will be noticeable in more complex scenes.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when the shadow is cast on a shadow catcher, is there a workaround for that?

Comment: This doesn't work with the self-cast shadows

Answer (score 8):

An alternative way to do this is to make the light have different colors for direct and indirect rays:

[image: 1]