# Toon Shader – Change Color of Shadows

Tags: cycles-render-engine, color, shadows

I made a character for a mobile game in Blender **rendered with Cycles**, and i used a toon material as shader. Now, for each toon material i create, i used an 'Image Texture' as a color gradient. I like the result, but i'm trying to work more on the shadows of the character, not cast shadows, but of the character itself. What i cannot figure out, using an image texture(png) as a color gradient, is there a way to change the colors of the shadows of the material? only of the shadows.
This is my character:[image]
Thank you in advance

Comment: I think you have more controll over the overall toon shader in the blender internal render engine...

Comment: Thank you, i was thinking if there is a way to do it in Cycles

Comment: If you can find a way using the blender internal render engine, you will also have the advantage of shorter render times

Comment: I would like to keep using Cycles because i already set lightining and all other materials/textures, and to not change it again, but in case i will make also a test with internal render

Comment: related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69709/how-to-change-the-shadow-color-in-blender-cycles

Comment: I think you are going to love the new "Shader to RGB" node in Eevee: https://youtu.be/10I2eWm7z70 As for Cycles, it appears that the Compositor is the only way to control such things. You can do a shadow pass and adjust color in compositor, maybe even try Cryptomatte which can auto output all materials and objects for separation and masking etc in compositing.

Comment: For quick reference, Cryptomatte and Shader to RGB node (Eevee only) are both available in Blender 2.80, not 2.79. I just saw another video on shadow color edits with Shader to RGB node. So cool! https://youtu.be/t91X4eukZY4

Comment: I like the character.  :)

Comment: What do you mean by " I use Image texture as color gradient"?

Answer (score 1):

### Eevee

Just an illustration of [Coby Randal's comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98275/toon-shader-cycles-change-color-of-shadows#comment228892_98275) - **Shader to RGB** node.

[image]

In case you want to keep AO ...

[image]

*Note: I wanted to composite AO pass (instead mix it in shader), but with this shader is AO pass wrong for some reason.*

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to change the color of shadows with only materials in cycles, I mean there is a way, but by doing so all shadows made by that object will be tinted (either on itself and that would include the background). A more controlled way would be by using the compositor in post, production.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the color of the shadows directly as far as I know, but via compositing you can. Try messing with a color balance node and see if it is to your liking. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/color/color_balance.html

edit: actually, if you are willing to switch to eevee, you might be get more control over your shadows.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t91X4eukZY4 Here is the tutorial I followed, except I didn't split the RGB, didn't use a diffuse shader to modify the base, and just simply used a color ramp with the different colors I wanted for the shaders. Try it c: