# Possible to give a shadow a different material?

Tags: materials, shaders, lighting

[image]

Hello.

Let say that in a this image, i'd like all shadows to be rendered as an red emissive material, is this possible in render ? procedurally, witouth any modifiers, just by the shader editor ?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86775/make-light-paths-only-pass-through-non-emitted-areas/86787#86787

Comment: ok so it's impossible then

Comment: there is a way to map indirect rays to an emissive material see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69709/how-to-change-the-shadow-color-in-blender-cycles/69719#69719

Comment: cool but this is a work shader option, i can i will not change the material :(