# How to set a material's color when shadowed

Tags: materials, shadows

I am trying to create a material that is normally white but turns blue in the shade.
I know I can do this by changing my lamp's color, but I don't want all the other materials to also turn blue.
Is there a way to do this in the material's settings?

Edit:
While I haven't found a way to do that in Cycles, I did find that in Eevee you can hook up a white Diffuse shader to the Shader to RGB node, and feed that through an RBG to BW node, then use the result as the fac input of either a MixRGB or Mix Shader node.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86775/make-light-paths-only-pass-through-non-emitted-areas/86787#86787

Comment: This might be just the right thing you are looking for. 
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/69711/60941

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks for the link.

Comment: @BlackCloud Thanks, if I can't find a better way I'll try that rout.